# Angular 2 named router outlet has weird url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm getting some weird urls when using Angular 2 router with named router outlet. I know there is a similar answer ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726345/angular-2-named-router-outlets-without-horrible-urls)), but my scenario is a bit different. If it was like that questions, I could fix this.

The point is, I have a restricted area in my application, an admin dashboard. This admin module is lazyloaded when user is autenticated, so I have 2 routing configurations, one when user is not logged in yet:

```
export const routing = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/adm/(adminoutlet:home)', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        canLoad: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: './../admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];
```

And one when he is already logged in:

```
export const adminRouting = [
    {
        path: 'adm',
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, outlet: "adminoutlet" },
            { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent, outlet: "adminoutlet" },
            // etc...
        ]
    },
];
```

And my admin html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: { adminoutlet: ['home']} }]">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="[{outlets: { adminoutlet: ['client']} }]">Client</a></li>
    <!-- etc... -->
</ul>

<router-outlet name="adminoutlet"></router-outlet>
```

This brings me 2 main problems:

- I can't make it work when not defining `/adm` on the admin module parent router. I prefer to use a simple url, e.g.: `mysite.com/home` instead of `mysite.com/adm/home`
- The url is very weird, like in the other question, it's something like this: mysite.com/adm/(adminoutlet:home), I'd like it to be `mysite.com/adm/home`, or even better, like the item before this, just a simple url: `mysite.com/home`

Currently it's working, but I'd like to fix these "issues".

How can I do this?

---

One of the problems I'm facing is when I remove the url prefix `adm`. Since it's being lazy loaded, I keep getting an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'

I think this has something to do with the error, but then again, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to make the url nicer?